# Error for invalid audio file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, actionscript

I'm working on a flash audio player, and I got it so that it can play an mp3 file. Now, I want to add an error handler so that I can know when/if the file I try to play is invalid. For example, if try to play a corrupted mp3 file or even a jpeg, it acts like it plays, but nothing happens.

I've tried adding an IOError listener like `_sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,handleIOError);`, but that only lets me know when a 404 error or other HTTP error happens.

Here is the code I use to play the audio:

```
_sound=new Sound();

_sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,handleIOError);
_sound.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,handleLoadProgress);

_urlRequest=new URLRequest(_url);
_sound.load(_urlRequest,createSoundLoaderContext());

_soundChannel=_sound.play(_position,0,createSoundTransform());
```

I've tried everything that I can think of. Does anyone know how I could find out when the file I try to play is not a valid audio file? Any workarounds would be helpful, even if they involve polling a property.

Comment: you could check the first few bytes of the loaded file and compare to the file format spec for mp3 (eg: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure)

Comment: @LeeBurrows Wow, that's an idea I hadn't thought of. I'll have to look into it more. Do you know if an mp3 always begins with `ID3` or `IHDR`? I couldn't seem to figure out exactly what that article was saying the structure was.

Comment: yeah, wasnt very clear to me either. this one is a bit better: http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html but i think youll need to do some research to figure it out. but i did have another idea (untested)... in addition to listening for progress+complete, listen for Event.ID3 - this fires when id3 info is available. if you havent had an id3 event when complete fires, you know its not a mp3 file. of course, that means loading the whole file whereas by checking the header, you could stop the unnecessary download.

Comment: FYI: I've currently decided that detecting an invalid mp3 isn't a crucial part of my project since I can detect a server error. I may change my mind in the future though.